Adding space between each category on the Y axis/each ribbon
Here is my what my data look like (the image). I am using ggplot and geom_alluvium. I am close but wanted to ask if there is any way I can add space between the ribbons/alluvial on the Y axis.
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Year, y = Category, alluvium = OPP)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = OPP, colour = OPP),
                alpha = 0.9, decreasing = FALSE, width = 1/4) +
  scale_x_continuous (breaks = seq(2015, 2016, 1),
    labels = c("General", "Specific"))+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    y = "",
    x = ""
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold'),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),`enter code here`
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    legend. Position = "none") +
scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set3") +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set3")


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Edit 1
Another potential approach could be to set colour to "white" and increase the linewidth to get more 'separation' between colours, e.g.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

df <- data.frame(Year = factor(c(rep(2015, 5), rep(2016, 5), rep(2017, 5))),
                 OPP = factor(LETTERS[1:5]),
                 Category = c(54, 14, 20, 2, 3,
                              10, 26, 38, 29, 2,
                              10, 20, 30, 40, 50))

ggplot(data = df,
         aes(x = Year, y = Category, alluvium = OPP)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = OPP, colour = OPP),
                alpha = 0.9, decreasing = FALSE, width = 1/4) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    y = "",
    x = ""
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold'),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set3") +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set3")



ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = Year, y = Category, alluvium = OPP)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = OPP),
                color = "white",
                decreasing = FALSE, alpha = 0.8,
                width = 1/4, linewidth = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    y = "",
    x = ""
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold'),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set3")


Created on 2024-12-20 with reprex v2.1.0
If you use alpha = 1 instead of alpha = 0.9 in the geom_alluvium() you wouldn't be able to see the lines at all. Would that type of approach suit your use-case?
Original answer:
I think alluvial plots are stacked on the y axis without gaps between lodes by design; perhaps consider using a Sankey plot instead?
E.g.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsankey)

df <- read.table(text = "Player  TG% Pts Team    Opp Year      Rd  Category
John    56  42  A       1   2016    1   Grnd1
James   94  64  B       2   2016    1   Grnd1
Jerry   85  78  C       1   2016    1   Grnd1
Daniel  97  51  D       2   2016    1   Grnd1
John    89  61  A       1   2016    1   Grnd1
James   65  26  B       1   2016    1   Grnd1
Jerry   73  34  C       1   2016    1   Grnd2
Daniel  73  40  D       2   2016    1   Grnd2
John    89  26  A       2   2016    1   Grnd3
James   92  42  B       3   2016    1   Grnd1
Jerry   89  25  C       3   2016    1   Grnd2
Daniel  80  41  D       3   2016    1   Grnd2
John    73  82  A       3   2016    1   Grnd3
James   73  41  B       3   2017    1   Grnd3
Jerry   89  76  C       3   2017    1   Grnd1
Daniel  91  77  D       3   2017    1   Grnd2", header = TRUE)

df_long <- df %>%
  make_long(Player, Opp, Category, Year)

df_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, 
           next_x = next_x, 
           node = fct_rev(node), 
           next_node = fct_rev(next_node),
           fill = factor(node),
           label = node)) +
  geom_sankey() +
  geom_sankey_label() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")



df_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, 
             next_x = next_x, 
             node = fct_rev(node), 
             next_node = fct_rev(next_node),
             fill = factor(node),
             label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(space = 10) +
  geom_sankey_label(space = 10) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


Created on 2024-12-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks, Jared. I initially wanted to create a sankey but since I want to show difference in proportions of same groups (A vs. A, B vs. B), I thought an alluvium might work better than sankey as a sankey is all about flows from the origin to destination. I have uploaded an image of my data (made-up data) if you think that might help?

Hi. I am unable to call ggsankey as when I try to install it from GITHUB it says Error in library(ggsankey): there is no package called 'ggsankey'.

That makes sense @ShaizaBushra. Thank you for adding the example data to your question, but please include the example data in a way that can be copy/pasted in future questions. I can see that an alluvial plot makes more sense for your data. I edited my answer with another potential solution, but please advise if this is not going to be suitable and I will search for another alternative.

Thank you so much!! It worked, I customized it based on my needs, and it worked perfectly fine.
